# How to update already tracked entity

Tags: entity-framework, tracking, dbcontext

Hello i have the following problem:

I am retrieving an entity using `EF Core` and then inside a transaction i try to `update` it.
The `update` throws exception if i try to change the `entity state` to `MODIFIED` **AFTER** i retrieve it from the database.

I understood later on that if i get the entity from the context, it is already tracked at that point, and all further updates do not need to imply changing the `entity state`.

Based on this assumption in the code below i have commented the state change.Unfortunately at the end the entity does not get updated.Even if i call `SaveChanges`.

```
public void SomeMethod(DbContext context)
{
   var entity=this.context.Find([some entity]);  // the entity is started to get tracked
   using(var tran=this.context.BeginTransaction())
   {
     try
     {
         //do some modifications on entity
         //  entity.Field1="tt";
         //  entity.Field2="ttx";
         //this.context(entity).State=State.Modified -> throws exception saying entity is already tracked
         this.context.SaveChanges();
         tran.Commit(); //  entity is not updated in the database !
     }catch
     {
        tran.Rollback();
     }
    }
}
```

**P.S** Besides this i have also tried to first change the entity state to `Detached` and then `Modified`.It still threw exception on the `Modified` line.

Could someone tell me how to perform an update on an already tracked entity?

**Update**
I have also tried without transaction, and still the tracked entity does not get changed.So this basically does not save changes:

```
var entity=this.context.Find([some entity]);
//do some changes on entity without changing the entity state
this.context.SaveChanges();
```

**Update 2**
Apparently the problem is from the updates.I am not just setting fields.
I am indeed somewhere creating a new entity.

Comment: Can you include in your code a simple example of the modifications you are making that result in the behaviour you've described? There may be something specific in the way you are making the changes.

Comment: I just set a string . Before the `SaveChanges` the entity looks ok , but the changes are not saved to the database.I am not creating a new object   if this is what you are thinking about.I am not pointing to another object to be clear .I change just fields.

Comment: Does it work if you change the query to find on the type, e.g: var entity=this.context.MyEntityType.Find(entityId); ?

Comment: I have solved the problem.The code corks without needing to change the state.The object wasn't updated in the database because somewhere in my code i was referencinga new object as the tracked entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the fact that i was instantiating a new entity in my code and this new entity was not tracked and ... i was expecting it the pop up in the database.
Once i changed to an entity that was being tracked , the update was succesful without requiring to change its state to `Modified` or otherwise.